# How to display serialize SQL data in php?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization

Bellow is the content of one SQL row in my wordpress db:

```
a:1:{s:5:"codes";a:5:{s:26:"AFFIL2014-I0AILGLNYG3UEAJI";a:3:{s:8:"maxcount";i:1;s:9:"leftcount";i:1;s:5:"users";s:0:"";}s:26:"AFFIL2014-XNAGS9YZMUMHD0PS";a:3:{s:8:"maxcount";i:1;s:9:"leftcount";i:1;s:5:"users";s:0:"";}s:26:"AFFIL2014-WO3X0YJLVHUZCZH6";a:3:{s:8:"maxcount";i:1;s:9:"leftcount";i:0;s:5:"users";a:1:{i:0;s:13:"testaccount22";}}s:26:"AFFIL2014-PEWHTTOWIZPXQJYU";a:3:{s:8:"maxcount";i:1;s:9:"leftcount";i:1;s:5:"users";s:0:"";}s:26:"AFFIL2014-Y6PTEJT2GLRIVF0J";a:3:{s:8:"maxcount";i:1;s:9:"leftcount";i:1;s:5:"users";s:0:"";}}}
```

I've never seen anything like this before. It looks like array, but I have no idea how to display this content on my PHP page.

Comment: It's serialize string. You need to use unserialize(http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to convert it back to an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called as a *[serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)* string. You need to use [*unserialize*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to converts it back into a PHP value.

**[Working Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5koXDF)**.

Comment: Great! Just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
$serialized = 'a:1:{s:5:"codes";a:5:{s:26:"AFFIL2014-I0AILGLNYG3UEAJI";a:3:{s:8:"maxcount";i:1;s:9:"leftcount";i:1;s:5:"users";s:0:"";}s:26:"AFFIL2014-XNAGS9YZMUMHD0PS";a:3:{s:8:"maxcount";i:1;s:9:"leftcount";i:1;s:5:"users";s:0:"";}s:26:"AFFIL2014-WO3X0YJLVHUZCZH6";a:3:{s:8:"maxcount";i:1;s:9:"leftcount";i:0;s:5:"users";a:1:{i:0;s:13:"testaccount22";}}s:26:"AFFIL2014-PEWHTTOWIZPXQJYU";a:3:{s:8:"maxcount";i:1;s:9:"leftcount";i:1;s:5:"users";s:0:"";}s:26:"AFFIL2014-Y6PTEJT2GLRIVF0J";a:3:{s:8:"maxcount";i:1;s:9:"leftcount";i:1;s:5:"users";s:0:"";}}}';


$unserialized = unserialize($serialized);


print_r($unserialized);
```